# What module to edit theme css in my drupal site

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a module that allows me to edit the theme css files within the drupal admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live CSS](http://drupal.org/project/live_css) is the module you are looking for:

> Edit CSS live within the page, and save the changes back to any css
>   file if you have write access.
>
> Additionally, this module enables the ability to render and perform
>   live editing of LESS stylesheets, included just like css files. Users
>   without the live editing permission will still see properly rendered
>   LESS displayed.